# Index.php instead Index.html, how to access, and where is the .htaccess file that i have apparently have to change?

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

so i downloaded a website template, unzipped it, and uploaded it on my host on bluehost, just to test it out. I tested several, but one of them didn't work, and it seems it's because that one has a Index.php instead of a Index.html file. I did some research, and stumbled upon things like redirecting the site to the php file instead of the html and such. Also, something with .htaccess...i have a lot of questions regarding this, but for now i just want to know how to treat this index.php like if it was an index.html.

I searched for .htaccess to change the parameter to make it load .php instead of .html

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the header
 *
 * Displays all of the head element and everything up until the page header div.
 *
 * @package Neve
 * @since   1.0.0
 */

$header_classes = apply_filters( 'nv_header_classes', 'header' );
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>
```

I just guess that i need to change the above header or some alternative of it. Please help. Thank you!

Btw: my website: https://sumproblems.com/ (i hope it is allowed to link this here. if not, sorry!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you are trying to view a WordPress theme, without the installation of WordPress.

You need first to download and [install WordPress on your hosting](https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/) and then upload this theme via WordPress admin (very easy). Good luck with that and enjoy WordPress

Comment: i already have wordpress installed, but uploading it through the wordpress panel sounds like a good idea, thank you, i'll try that out! did the 'wpml-config.xml' file gave you the idea that this is a wordpress template? or how do you figured that out else?

Comment: I was looking at your files directory and saw that it's a wordpress theme

Comment: how did you look into it? developer console? or is there some work around? and do you have btw any other little tipps that i should now? thank you for your help!

Comment: The link you shared was 'open', meaning anyone could see the directory structure. always a good idea is to block it. Also, WordPress themes are very easy to identify, they have a common structure of files, and usually it easy to identify

Comment: yes, i did. thank you. i just uploaded a theme. a previous wordpress installation i had, was uninstalled by me. i now created two new, each in their own folders. now i can continue testing out templates online. thank you for your help. how can i block it so that the link isn't open like that?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the *index.php* is the only file named *index* in the directory, the webserver will show it.

Not sure if you have tried this but, remove everything you've uploaded (in this case, the templates) from the main website directory (where you've placed the templates) and just upload the one with the *index.php* file. Usually, there's no need to change anything on the *.htaccess* file, as the web server will recognize that he needs to show that file in the first place.

About the location of the *.htaccess* file: It should be on the main directory.

If this does not work, post a link to Pastebin or any other service of your choice with the contents of the *.htaccess* file so we can take a look.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. it's just the 'neve' template now, and it doesn't work if i access it by directly clicking on the folder-link or if i use http://sumproblems.com/neve/index.php